# How to change notifications settings for new Sentry On-Premise users?

Tags: docker, ldap, sentry

I am configuring a Sentry on premise installation (using the default Docker image) with LDAP authentication, so any time a user logs-in for the first time a Sentry user is created under the hood.

The default notifications settings for these new users are pretty annoying, because the **Workflow Notifications** flag is set to `Always`, and ideally we'd like it to be `Only On Issues I Subscribe To`.

I know that each new user can go and update their settings by hand, but this is a largish corporation and I don't want to be directing every single person to change that when they get tired of receiving too many notifications and come asking me.

So in brief: is there any way to update the default notifications settings for new Sentry users?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty way to achieve this, I am applying this patch when building our custom Sentry on Premise Docker image, alongside the steps where we copy the config files.

```
diff --git a/src/sentry/api/endpoints/user_notification_details.py b/src/sentry/api/endpoints/user_notification_details.py
index a382b6b7e3..2edd21efc7 100644
--- a/src/sentry/api/endpoints/user_notification_details.py
+++ b/src/sentry/api/endpoints/user_notification_details.py
@@ -36,7 +36,7 @@ USER_OPTION_SETTINGS = {
     },
     'workflowNotifications': {
         'key': 'workflow:notifications',
-        'default': UserOptionValue.all_conversations,  # '0'
+        'default': UserOptionValue.participating_only,  # '0'
         'type': int,
     }
 }
```